# MS Office Automation transfer table from excel to word using PublishObjects.Add

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, automation

For a project I'm working on, we need to copy data from Excel sheets into new tables within a Word document and have a strategy that works... in most cases.

First, we do

```
string file = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() +
    ".mht");
object sheetObj = sheetName;
object trueObj = true;
Excel.PublishObject obj = workbook.PublishObjects.Add(Excel.XlSourceType.xlSourceSheet, file,
sheetObj);
obj.Publish(trueObj);
```

then
    Document tempDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(file);
and read templDocument into the targe Word doc.
...

In a couple of cases, we're seeing problems. (The problems are illustrated in the example files at http://thinkscience.us/office/examples.zip) 
1) the big text files show text truncation between Excel and the exported .mht
2) the 'nutritional' files show the addition of several lines of white space between the Excel data and the .mht.

I've tried several variations on the parameters to PublishObjects.Add (using a range rather than an entire sheet).  The add method includes an optional XlHtmlType parameter that only works with value XlHtmlType.xlHtmlStatic.

Has anyone used PublishObjects.Add or another strategy to transfer sheets from Excel to Word, preserving as much formatting as possible and not interfering with the system clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

I found an article which might meet your needs, but it's not using Office automation, it's using a library called Spire.Office. Check: [How to Maintain Formatting of Cells when Copying Cells from Excel to Word](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/46385-How-to-Maintain-Formatting-of-Cells-when-Copying-Cells-from-Excel-to-Word.aspx). 
[image]